Nuxt.js global middleware keep redirecting me to login after refershing a page after authentification
So i have a globabl middleware that is supposed to portect other routes based on if a token is in local storage
import { parseCookie } from '~/utils/parseCookie';

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  const { $locally } = useNuxtApp();
  let token = $locally.getItem('token'); 

  
  if (token) {
    console.log('Token found in localStorage:', token); 
    return; 
  }

  else {
    console.log('else')
    const cookies = useRequestHeaders().cookie;
    if (cookies) {
        console.log('cookies')

      const parsedCookies = parseCookie(cookies);
      token = parsedCookies.token;
    }

    if (!token && to.path !== '/login') {
        $locally.setItem('msg','zefze'); 

        console.log('Redirecting to login');

         navigateTo('/login', { external: true });

      }
  }

  console.log('Token:', token);

  
});

im using "$locally" here as import plugin because using localstorage gives me an error "local storage is not defined" here is the locally.js plugin
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    return {
      provide: {
        locally: {
          getItem(key) {
            if (process.server) {
             
            } else {
              return localStorage.getItem(key);
            }
          },
          setItem(key, value) {
            if (process.server) {
              
            } else {
              localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
  });
  

the issue here is after authentification it redirct me back to login regardless if the token is in local storage or not and im not too sure why
Tried Refershing after authentification redircted me back to login regardless of the existence of the token

Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you create a [mre] on CodeSandbox or StackBlitz and [edit] the question to include it?

Because the localStorage is not available in client-side, when you refresh the page, the node will run the global middleware in the node-side since Nuxt is SSR in default, so it will redirect you to the login page. The solution is storing your token into a cookie instead of localStorage

Thank you saved me a world of headache it works perfectly now
